# Power BI Embedded Content Not loading in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, powerbi

We are developing a Cordova app that displays a Power BI Report (inside a iframe) using Power BI Embedded framework. It works fine in the Android version but gives an error in iOS.

"Blocked a frame with origin app.powerbi.com from accessing a frame with origin "file". The frame requesting access has a
protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match."

[iOS Preview in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NlBd.jpg)

[Error message from developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ghv6.jpg)

Is there any work around to get over this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try to go through this and it might solve your problem?
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Mobile-Apps/IOS-App-Not-Working-Refreshing/td-p/72108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Working.

Please refer below thread for the fix.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-Embedded-Content-Not-loading-in-iOS/m-p/929432